# Bold in Area 51 comments break in the notification inbox

Tags: bug, comments, area-51, notifications

When someone leaves a comment on a proposed Area 51 [question](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/75348/hebrew-language/80400#80400) with bold in the comment, it shows up as a bunch of asterisks.

Picture:

[image]

Comment: Just to make sure, **this bold text** appears fine in the notification? :)

Comment: Yup, appears fine (though not bold) ;-)

Comment: What about the full inbox in your network profile? How is it displayed in there?

Comment: Your first comment appears with the asterisks; in my Meta profile inbox, your second comment appears with bold, in the universal inbox it appears without bold or asterisk.

Comment: I'm not sure what it's supposed to look like, so I'm not sure how much of that is a bug....what's in the question is certainly a bug.